# How to use the effects output of a MANOVA model to calculate BLUEs? (without an intercept)

Tags: manova, blue, asreml

So my team wants a single best linear unbiased estimate (BLUE) using 2 response variables.  I have asremlR and here is my code to produce the model:

```
>asreml_Iblock_di <- asreml(fixed=cbind(sb_pro,la_pro) ~name+year+linmat, random = ~rep + 
                Block+ rep*Block, data=e,family=asr_binomial(link="logit",dispersion =NA,
                total =5),na.action = na.method(x="include")
                     )
```

I am then able to pull out the effect of 'name'(which are different sobyean genotypes).  With my non-multivariate models (just sb_pro or la_pro), a 'intercept effect' is included in this output and I can calcualte the BLUEs by:

```
>blues_di <- coef(asreml_Iblock_di )$fixed
>blues_di <- blues_di + blues_di["(Intercept)",]
>blues_di <- blues_di[rownames(blues_di) != "(Intercept)",,drop = FALSE`
```

I realize that by using both sb_pro and la_pro, that an intercept is not included in the output and so I can not calculate the BLUEs as I usually do.  For a Manova, is there something to use instead of the intercept???

Whoever reads this, thank you for your time....
-Sarah